# how to add php gd with composer (laravel 8)

Tags: php, composer-php, require, gd, dompdf

I trying to add php gd to the composer.json.
I want to install php gd because of the following error :

```js
The PHP GD extension is required, but is not installed.
```

The error was caused by dompdf as dompdf requires php gd to process images.
I tried the following command :

```html
composer require "ext-gd:*" --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Without any result even tough ext-gd was added to the composer.json.
Does anyone know a solution to my problem?
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't install GD with Composer. Composer manages other PHP source that your project relies on, but GD is not PHP source -- it's a native PHP extension module like `ext-curl` or `ext-mysqli`. Adding `ext-gd:*` to your composer.json simply means, "This project requires the GD extension to be installed." In order to actually *install* that extension, you'll need to drop to your OS-level tools. If you're on a Debian-based system, that'll likely be something like:

```
sudo apt install php-gd
```

Or, for a RedHat-based system, something like:

```
sudo dnf install php-gd
```

Once done, run your `composer install` again and you should be good.